# Прозрачный navbar bootstpap4

Tags: bootstrap4

Подскажите как на bootstrap4 у nav-bar сделать прозрачный фон. Перелопатил кучу статей, но ни один вариант не срабатывает. Самое интересное, если задать фон допустим red - все реагирует, а если написать transparent или попробовать во что- то обернуть или повесить какие-то стандартные классы, то ничего не работает. Возможно на данный момент в bootstrap что-то поменялось?

Answer (score -1):

В Bootstrap 4.1 есть класс `bg-transparent` и если его задать для `nav` то элемент будет прозрачным. В Bootstrap 4 Вы можете объявить свой класс с необходимыми свойствами и затем задать его для элемента.